# Trying to inverse WHERE clause but it doesn't add up

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a SQL query to show me results from some tables.
The query with no WHERE clause returns 1087 results

```
SELECT hf.id, hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`,hf.`sites_organisation_code`,hf.`eric_site_id` FROM `hospital_final` hf
left join nhs_choices nc on nc.OrganisationID = hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`
left join sites s on s.`Organisation Code` = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
left join eric_site es on es.site_code = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
```

IF I add the WHERE clause in I get 260 results

```
SELECT hf.id, hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`,hf.`sites_organisation_code`,hf.`eric_site_id` FROM `hospital_final` hf
left join nhs_choices nc on nc.OrganisationID = hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`
left join sites s on s.`Organisation Code` = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
left join eric_site es on es.site_code = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
WHERE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( s.NAME, "'", '')), " ", '')) LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", ''))AND  (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", '')) LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( es.site_name, "'", '')), " ", ''))
```

Now what I would like to do is to find all of the results that are not in the where clause. The first obvious solution to me was to surround that in brackets and prefix it with NOT

```
SELECT hf.id, hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`,hf.`sites_organisation_code`,hf.`eric_site_id` FROM `hospital_final` hf
left join nhs_choices nc on nc.OrganisationID = hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`
left join sites s on s.`Organisation Code` = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
left join eric_site es on es.site_code = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
WHERE NOT ((REPLACE( (REPLACE( s.NAME, "'", '')), " ", '')) LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", ''))AND  (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", '')) LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( es.site_name, "'", '')), " ", '')))
```

But this only returned 370 results

I tried to do it explicitly this time

```
SELECT hf.id, hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`,hf.`sites_organisation_code`,hf.`eric_site_id` FROM `hospital_final` hf
left join nhs_choices nc on nc.OrganisationID = hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`
left join sites s on s.`Organisation Code` = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
left join eric_site es on es.site_code = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
WHERE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( s.NAME, "'", '')), " ", ''))  NOT LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", ''))OR  (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", '')) NOT LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( es.site_name, "'", '')), " ", ''))OR (REPLACE( (REPLACE( es.site_name, "'", '')), " ", '')) NOT LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( s.NAME, "'", '')), " ", ''))
```

and again only getting 370.

Now according to my understanding of the fundamentals of maths 1087-260 ≠ 370.

I can write it all out into a subquery which returns the expected 827, but is that necessary?

```
SELECT hf.id, hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`,hf.`sites_organisation_code`,hf.`eric_site_id` FROM `hospital_final` hf
left join nhs_choices nc on nc.OrganisationID = hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`
left join sites s on s.`Organisation Code` = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
left join eric_site es on es.site_code = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
WHERE hf.id NOT IN
(SELECT hf.id FROM `hospital_final` hf
left join nhs_choices nc on nc.OrganisationID = hf.`nhs_choices_organisationid`
left join sites s on s.`Organisation Code` = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
left join eric_site es on es.site_code = hf.`sites_organisation_code`
WHERE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( s.NAME, "'", '')), " ", ''))  LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", ''))AND  (REPLACE( (REPLACE( nc.OrganisationName, "'", '')), " ", '')) LIKE (REPLACE( (REPLACE( es.site_name, "'", '')), " ", '')))
```

Comment: 1) Null handling 2) WHERE on column from `LEFT JOIN` makes it a `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: What @LukaszSzozda said. If you're not checking for nulls, you're missing all the records where the LEFT JOIN didn't result in a matching record.

Comment: Points to you, though, for remembering that `NOT (A and B)` equals `(NOT A) or (NOT B)`.  Not everybody remembers that rule.

Answer (score 3):

You have some complicated `WHERE` expression, but that doesn't matter.  What is important is that the inverse of:

```
WHERE <something>
```

is NOT

```
WHERE NOT <something>
```

That is because expressions can evaluate to `NULL` -- and this is especially true with outer joins.

The proper inverse would be:

```
WHERE (NOT <something> OR
       <something> IS NULL
      )
```

Comment: Nice clean example (as always!)